# How to calculate $\partial_t\sqrt g$ in Riemannian geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from 1706th page of Zhao Liang's *[The first eigenvalue of Laplace operator under powers of mean curvature flow](http://xueshu.baidu.com/s?wd=paperuri%3A%28dd325744683216d9b17ff64cde850cf3%29&filter=sc_long_sign&tn=SE_xueshusource_2kduw22v&sc_vurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fmathscinet-getitem%3Fmr%3D3057347&ie=utf-8&sc_us=6811413051064070287)*.

$M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold. $g_{ij}$ is Riemannian metric, $h_{ij}$ is second fundamental form,$h^{ij}=g^{ip}g^{jq}h_{pq}$, and $H=g^{ij}h_{ij}$. $\nabla$ is Riemannian connect, and $\nabla^pH=g^{pl}\nabla_lH$. $h$ is a constant independ to $x$. Besides, $dim M=n$.

Why there are two gradient at last, I think it should be the inner of two gradient. Besides, how to deal the term with $\frac{2}{n}$ ? I think it should be by integrating by parts, then $\partial_t\sqrt g$ has $\frac{n}{2}$, but I don't know how to calculate $\partial_t\sqrt g$. In fact, I get a complex result without usefull.

> [image]

Comment: You should Google how to  derivate a determinant. Then, it is easy.